# Endless EditTextfields

Tags: android

my question is, i want to program something like a Excel table. So the user has got endless EditText fields he can write in informations.

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Vorgänge"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:shadowColor="#00a9a6cc"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"/>

         <EditText
             android:layout_width="125dp"
             android:layout_height="25dp"
             android:id="@+id/editText2"
             android:text="Status"
             android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
             android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
             android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:shadowColor="#00a9a6cc"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"/>

          <EditText
              android:layout_width="125dp"
              android:layout_height="25dp"
              android:id="@+id/editText5"
              android:text="Priorität"
              android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
              android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
              android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:shadowColor="#00a9a6cc"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"/>

           <EditText
               android:layout_width="125dp"
               android:layout_height="25dp"
               android:id="@+id/editText3"
               android:text="Abgabedatum"
               android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
               android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:textColor="#000000"
               android:shadowColor="#00a9a6cc"
               android:clickable="true"
               android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is what i have until now. And now under the textfields written below there should be endless editText fields.

Thx for your help guys

Max :)